# How do i use SendMessage to simulate keys combination click to a specific software window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a running software in this case for example Paint.exe

Now i want to simulate a combination of: Ctrl+R click on the Paint.exe window.

I know the Paint.exe handle and i also know how to bring the Paint.exe handle window to the front and to the center of screen.

The problem is how to use the SendMessage ?

I added to the top of my form1:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(
                  int hWnd,      // handle to destination window
                  uint Msg,       // message
                  long wParam,  // first message parameter
                  long lParam   // second message parameter
                  );
```

Also in form1 top i think i need to do something like:

```
public const int <WM_YOURMESSAGE> = <yourvalue>;
```

But not sure how it should be like.

And in the end i should call the SendMessage function when i want to simulate the ctrl+r click.

What should it be like the public const int...and how to use the SendMessage ?
And how reliable using this way to simulate ctrl+r ?

Comment: Windows is designed for things like this, so it's quite reliable. There's many ways to do what you're trying to do, but teaching a man to fish, it's a great idea to take Spy++ and see what happens when you *normally* press `Ctrl+R` in Paint. Then just send the same relevant messages from your application.